# Possible to save (and load) Column Widths in a C# DataGridView but keep column settings to FILL?

Tags: c#, datagridview, resize

I have been given a brief to change one of our products because users apparently manage to hide all the columns in a DataGridView and can't find them again

(1) Users must be able to resize the columns and
(2) the widths of the columns needs to be saved and reloaded when they return and
(3) the columns cannot ever, EVER be hidden. Any change of the column width by the user must never resize other columns off the visible window

For the third part, which is currently what is broken, the user resizes column A to fill the ENTIRE grid and columns B and C are hidden off the side. Or the resize columns then shrink the window, hiding hiding stuff that doesn't fit

Setting all Columns to AutoSizeMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill, Resize=true gives us the "no hide any columns" fine. Users can resize, and no column can ever be hidden

However you cannot load and save the widths since in this mode column.Width = WHATEVER does nothing and is ignored by the component

So you can set AutoSizeMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None then Width=SAVEDWIDTH but then the user can resize columns off the screen again

So you can then set AutoSizeMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill but that then overrides the width settings just loaded!

Is there a way to do this?

Note: My current code loads and saves the columns fine.

I abuse the AutoSizeMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill which makes a nice looking grid, then set to AutoSizeMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None and load the settings from disk (if any)

It's at this point the user can now resize their columns and hide stuff!